# Getting error when using onClick() events on Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm new on Android, I've started a newbie app to playing with the event listeners which change the text of a button when I made click on it... following the developer's guide ( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventListeners ), I've created the layout with the views ( a TextView and the Button ) and a main Activity. But when I compiles de code, send the .apk ( Eclipse ) to the ADV and starts the app I get that list of errors:

```
04-26 21:37:22.615: D/dalvikvm(637): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-26 21:37:23.845: I/dalvikvm(637): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-26 21:37:24.205: I/dalvikvm(637): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-26 21:37:24.805: D/AndroidRuntime(637): Shutting down VM
04-26 21:37:24.805: W/dalvikvm(637): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.examples.fragmentos/com.examples.fragmentos.TestFragmentosActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at com.examples.fragmentos.TestFragmentosActivity.<init>(TestFragmentosActivity.java:12)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  ... 11 more
04-26 21:37:25.415: I/dalvikvm(637): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-26 21:37:25.485: I/dalvikvm(637): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-26 21:37:26.325: I/dalvikvm(637): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-26 21:37:26.375: I/dalvikvm(637): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-26 21:37:26.535: I/dalvikvm(637): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-26 21:37:26.655: I/dalvikvm(637): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-26 21:42:26.155: I/Process(637): Sending signal. PID: 637 SIG: 9
```

here is the code:

```
package com.examples.fragmentos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class TestFragmentosActivity extends Activity {

    Button b = ( Button )findViewById( R.id.buttonInfo );

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        b.setOnClickListener( mbuttonInfoListener );

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    // Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
    private OnClickListener mbuttonInfoListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick( View v ) {
          b.setText("Ey, don't touch me!");
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the initialization of `b`:

```
Button b = ( Button )findViewById( R.id.buttonInfo );
```

You can only find views **after** setting the contents of the activity, i.e. after calling `setContentView()`.

Try this:

```
private Button b;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonInfo);
    b.setOnClickListener(mbuttonInfoListener);
}
```

Also, make sure you have a button with an id set to `buttonInfo` in your layout.

Comment: Aye, that's it!. I thought the setContentView() method shows the "view" like other languages/ frameworks based on MVC...
Thank so much to both of you guys! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a NullPointerException in the new activity. It is correctly started but crashes. The error is shown here:

```
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at ndroid.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
04-26 21:37:24.906: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at com.examples.fragmentos.TestFragmentosActivity.init>(TestFragmentosActivity.java:12)
```

Check your code in TestFragmentosActivity line 12 as the problem is over there.

EDIT--

I guess line 12 is this:

```
Button b = ( Button )findViewById( R.id.buttonInfo );
```

You are trying to get the view before it's created. This should be called after you set the view with setContentView. One easy solution is to declare the object like this:

```
Button b;
```

and at the end of onCreate function add:

```
b = ( Button )findViewById( R.id.buttonInfo );
```